# Using Unity's new input system how do I get the value from a 1d axis i have created?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Trying to figure out unity's new input system. I have set up the actions as a 1D axis where W is the positive direction and S is the negative direction. https://ibb.co/gTWGd2W. There is a "Player Input" component where the script for the actions is. https://ibb.co/ZzmsszV. The script is below. I am trying to get the value from the 1d axis and apply it to the paddle in update. but what value i am referencing with value.Get(); obviously isn't right since it is returning 0 at all times. I am not sure what i should be referencing or how to even find that information. I have spent hours searching and can't figure out what I need

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PaddleBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject leftPaddle;
    public GameObject rightPaddle;

    public float moveValueLeft;
    public float moveValueRight;

    public int moveSpeed = 10;

    void Update()
    {
        leftPaddle.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, moveValueLeft, 0) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        rightPaddle.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, moveValueRight, 0) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnMovement(InputValue value)
    {
        moveValueLeft = value.Get<float>();
        moveValueRight = value.Get<float>();
    }
}
```

I know I'm making a stupid mistake but not sure how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value in multiple ways, the easier is to link it thought inspector using the PlayerInput component and marking the behaviour field as Invoke Unity Events, then just drag and drop your components to answer the input (just remember that the method signature must be the same). You can read further about it here https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Components.html

[image]